# Jquery Image Preview on Hover with AJAX data

Tags: image, jquery, rollover

I have an image preview plugin. It works perfectly with images that are already in the page.
like:

```
<a href='ImgHandler.ashx?Id=5' class='preview' title='Landscape'>
<img height='18' width='18' class='ImgInCell' src='ImgHandler.ashx?Id=5' alt='Landscape' /></a>
```

But When i load the same type of code through Ajax on a DIV layer the image hover preview is not working.

```
<a id="LinkPic" class="preview" title="Land Scape" href="ImgHandler.ashx?Id=5">
<img id="ImgPic" style="height:50px;width:50px;" src="ImgHandler.ashx?Id=5" alt="Land Scape">
</a>
```

Then i used firebug and copied the source after the load of AJAX; created a html page; then on loading it, I see the image hover on the AJAX Image is working Fine.
The Jquery code for The image preview is called by following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    imagePreview();
});
```

I think it is not working due to the `document.ready` . How do i make the image preview work on AJAX data(Image)??

Calling the `imagePreview();` after the AJAX call didnt help.

Comment: can you re-load the jquery plugin after AJAX call?

Comment: re-load?? I didnt quite understant.. I called the `imagePreview();` after completion of AJAX call. That didn't work, however it caused duplicate Image preview on the working ones :@

Comment: check following solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079874/jquery-image-preview-that-work-on-ajax-embedded-image-links

Comment: Nope, it didnt work. I added  `$("a#LinkPic").hover(function (e) {...}` and `$("a#LinkPic").mousemove(function (e) {...}` after the AJAX call, but didnt work.

Comment: @Ruchan I meant, after completion of AJAX call, use the code inside `imagePreview()` itself instead of calling `imagePreview();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found no other way than to insert the jquery code into the AJAX called document (partial view) with change in class like `imgpreview2`, and now its working fine.